# ASP.NET 5: Azure web app CORS stop working after delay

Tags: asp.net, cors, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core

I have ASP.NET 5 web site (dnx451) hosted in Azure. 
It works fine for an hour or so after the deployment and then CORS feature stop working. Other services like DI, Authorization and MVC are still functioning.

Here is Startup.cs code:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        configureCors(services);
        services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
                  options.Filters.Add(new ErrorFilter());
        });

   }

    private static void configureCors(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors();


        services.ConfigureCors(x => x.AddPolicy("allowAll", p=>p.AllowAnyOrigin().
        AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod()));
    }
```

App configuration:

```
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IApplicationEnvironment env,  ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {

            app.UseMiddleware<StaticFileMiddleware>(new StaticFileOptions());
            app.UseErrorPage();

            // Add MVC to the request pipeline.
            app.UseMvc();
            app.UseCors("allowAll");

        }
```

Local version has CORS all the time but Azure web has it only in the first 1-2 hours (depending on the usage). I guess CORS disappears when Azure restarts the app.

It is strange. Does anyone have the same problem?

Comment: Does moving `app.UseCors("allowAll");` above `UseMvc()` help?

Comment: In this case I've got 
`ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.`
in Microsoft.AspNet.Cors.Core.CorsService.ApplyResult -> >Microsoft.AspNet.Loader.IIS.HeaderCollection.Add(String key, String[] value)
Its moved above:
`
            app.UseCors("allowAll");
            app.UseMvc();
`

Comment: I meant moving, not copying.

Comment: I have another web.api service built with OWIN and deployed to Azure. No problems with CORS (using this code)
 `public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app){
   app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
}`

Comment: My point is that the MVC middleware (`UseMvc()`) usually ends the request (e.g. does not call `_next()`) so adding CORS _after_ MVC might result in not applying the CORS middleware.

Comment: Make sense! Need to find out why do I have 'Duplicate key' issue when I change the order and place UseCors before UseMvc. It might be related to Oauth JWT configuration that I also have.

It is strange is that CORS is actually working fine in the beginning and stop working after a while. My guess is that after app restart, Mvc ends the request pipeline while initial start doesn't do this.

Comment: Forgot to say that I also have [EnableCors("allowAll")] attribute applied to the base controller.

Comment: You should use one of them. So either the `[EnableCors]` attribute _or_ `UseCors()` as they add the given key to an internal dictionary. That might explain the duplicate key exception.

Comment: Still not sure about the odd behavior. But using the middleware in the right order and not enabling CORS twice might help you out here.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Henk, I was able to fix the problem:

I had both `[EnableCors]` attribute and  `app.UseCors()` startup call. After removing UseCors, the problem disappeared.

However it is still strange why Cors is working temporarily when both options are in place.

**Update:**
As for https://github.com/aspnet/CORS/issues/36

You need not call `services.AddCors()` here as AddMvc internally already does that.